# javascript onsubmit change field value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a javascript chrome extension which contains a content_script which:

- reads user submitted data
- modifies the user data when required
- removes a prefix "myprefix:" which the user might have inserted and
- submits the modified text instead.

I have already written some code which is successfully updating the required values (I can see the input field values being changed on submit, right before the browser navigates away from the page). However, sometimes are submitted the unmodified values (the value before the prefix is removed), and this happens intermittently.

So far I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    onsubmitModifier();
}

function onsubmitModifier() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        document.forms[i].addEventListener("submit", function () {
            var elementList = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            for (var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
                if (elementList[i].value.toLowerCase().startsWith("myprefix:")) {
                    // data modification is removed for testing
                    elementList[i].value = elementList[i].value.substring("myprefix:".length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be you're missing the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: You say it happens "intermittently": is there any pattern to the cases in which it happens?

Comment: Is it possible that a form is added dynamically **after** `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: @Xan, I'm **guessing** that if a form is added after `DOMContentLoaded`, then I wouldn't be getting the "Submit" events, and I am getting them (the values are being modified, but the submitted value is not always the modified one).

Comment: This is just a hint (I didn't have the time to test it): Inside the submit handler of a single form you are looping over `every` input element on the page, even if it is not part of the current form

Comment: @devnull69, you are right, however that's the intended use; I want to save any data which the user has prefixed with `"myprefix:"` (having said that I don't see why this could be a source of problems?)

Comment: @kmoe, the first time I open a page after reloading the extension files, it often works (modified value submitted). Afterwards (reloading the webpage), it works intermittently around once every five times.

Comment: How do you inject your script?

Comment: I am loading the js file through the manifest.json as so:
"content_scripts": [{
 "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
 "js": ["form_editor.js"],
 "run_at": "document_start"

Comment: Should the values really be modified right before "submission", or is it also acceptable if you edit the input after the input field has changed? Look up event delegation.

Comment: Could it be an issue of chrome still carrying on with the form data submission while my extension is processing the data? Is there a way to cancel the current submission and resubmit once I have finished my processing?

Comment: it looks like that the problem occurs only in a select few websites, one on which being amazon.com. Not even returning false onsubmit works to stop submission, while in most other websites, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try first stop the default event, and then call `form.submit()` in an `setTimeout` block.